# connection not established. error in Mail::Sender

Tags: perl, email

I'm using Mail::Sender , I'm getting the error message as

> connection not established.

I'm using OpenMultipart to fill up the hash.

when this error will come? how to solve this?

If I send 10 mails,  only 2 mails successful send , remaining mails got this error.

```
$Msg = new Mail::Sender (
                {
                smtp => $EMAIL_Globals::SMTP_IP,
                from => $FromAddress,
                debug_level => 4,
                }
                );

eval {
        $Msg->OpenMultipart({
                        from => ${$Email_details}[10],
                        to =>  ${$Email_details}[9],
                        subject => $Subject,
                        debug => '/tmp/zkMailFlow.log',
                        multipart => 'related',
                        })
        ->Part({ctype => 'multipart/alternative'})
                ->Part({ctype => 'text/html', disposition => 'NONE', msg => " 
                                <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC -//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN>
                                <html> xxxxx
                                </html>" })
                ->EndPart("multipart/alternative");
        for ( ;$i<= $Length; $i+=4) {
                $Count=$i;
                $Flag = 1;
                $Msg->Attach({
                                description => 'xxxxx',
                                ctype => 'image/jpeg',
                                encoding => 'base64',
                                disposition => "attachment; filename=$Page_id[$i];",
                                file => '/path/files/i',
                                });
        }
        $Msg->Close();
} or print "Error sending mail: $Mail::Sender::Error\n";

if ($Mail::Sender::Error)
{
        if ($Msg->{"error"} eq -3)
        {
                return('FAILURE',$Mail::Sender::Error);
        }
        else
        {
                return('Error',$Mail::Sender::Error);
        }
}

if ( ref ($Msg) ne 'Mail::Sender' ){
        return ('Error',$Mail::Sender::Error);
}
else{
        return('SUCCESS',"Mail Sent Successfully");
}
```

debug log file content

```
>> 220 nsmtpin.xxxxb.co.in ESMTP Service (Lotus Domino Release 8.5.2) ready at Wed, 10 Apr 2013 00:42:28 +0530
<< EHLO localhost
>> 250-nsmtpin.xxxxb.co.in Hello localhost ([10.2.252.251]), pleased to meet you
>> 250-HELP
>> 250-SIZE 5324800
>> 250 PIPELINING
<< MAIL FROM:<xxxxx@xxxxB.com>
>> 250 xxxxxx@xxxxB.com... Sender OK
<< RCPT TO:<xxx@xxxxB.com>
>> 250 xxx@xxxxB.com... Recipient OK
<< DATA
>> 354 Enter message, end with "." on a line by itself
<< To: xxxx@xxxxB.com
<< From: xxx.xxx@xxxxB.com
<< Subject: Testing
<< Date: Wed, 10 Apr 2013 00:35:42 +0530
<< X-Mailer: Perl script "Email_Resender"
<<  using Mail::Sender 0.8.16 by Jenda Krynicky, Czechlands
<<  running on localhost (127.0.0.1)
<<  under account "root"
<< Message-ID: <20130409_190542_084621.Mitesh.Shah@xxxxB.com>
<< MIME-Version: 1.0
<< Content-type: multipart/related;
<<  boundary="Message-Boundary-by-Mail-Sender-1365534342"
<< 
<< This message is in MIME format. Since your mail reader does not understand
<< this format, some or all of this message may not be legible.
<< 
<< --Message-Boundary-by-Mail-Sender-1365534342
<< Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="Part-Message-Boundary-by-Mail-Sender-1365534342_2"
<< 
<< 
<< --Part-Message-Boundary-by-Mail-Sender-1365534342_2
<< Content-type: text/html
<< Content-transfer-encoding: 7BIT
<< 
<<  
<< 
<<                          <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC -//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN>
<<                          <html>
<<                          
<<                          </html>
<< --Part-Message-Boundary-by-Mail-Sender-1365534342_2--
<< 
<< --Message-Boundary-by-Mail-Sender-1365534342
<< Content-type: image/jpeg; name="20130408_112508_2792230080_1_4.jpg"
<< Content-description: fax1 jpg
<< Content-transfer-encoding: base64
<< Content-disposition: attachment; filename=08042013/20130408_112508_2792230080_1_4.jpg;
<< 
<< /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAzABiAAD//gAbPFVOU1BFQ0lGSUVEPgoyNzkyMjMwMDgwCv/bAEMABQME
<< BAQDBQQEBAUFBQYHDAgHBwcHDwsLCQwRDxISEQ8RERMWHBcTFBoVEREYIRgaHR0fHx8TFyIkIh4k
<< HB4fHv/AAAsIA+gDIAEBEQD/xAAdAAEAAgMBAQEBAAAAAAAAAAAABQYDBAcCAQgJ/8QAdhAAAQME
<< fWbj6/DL+rsQgf8Ad/VX4L6Wzr/beo2PTcWQpy9N3Fn0JtP/AGRwrACD9St8T9RNf1yRy4DkAFa7
<< gHeqj8nvVvxzHbhfrq+GINvjrkPrPsQkbOvefYB7yK578HfqZL6lYhMeukL4qv0N7b8UoIKWHh4s
<< jkjkT7dBQH2VhR8HzCUFRRdcxSVq5K1kcobPbufW8+wr1/g/4Z/S+Z/rLK/aqUt3RXBokRLDjF2m
<< qDnPxpd3kuOEfilXMer9VbbXSHAkNpQbQ+spAHJdxklR+snxO5r180eA/wBCufeEn95T5o8B/oVz
<< 7wk/vKfNHgP9CufeEn95T5o8B/oVz7wk/vKfNJgP9CufeEn95Uc50G6QuuKcdwKzOOLJUpa0KUpR
<< PmSSrZP1mvnzBdHfzfWP/ZK/aoOgfR4EEdPrHsHf8ir++p+P0z6exw8GsKx5Pjnbn+5zR3217U9u
<< 3u1Wdvp9giEJQnDcd4pAA/3LYPYf/Fr78gMG/I3Hfutj9inyAwb8jcd+62P2KfIDBvyNx37rY/Yp
<< 8gMG/I3Hfutj9ivbWC4U0dtYjYEE+1NsYH/5Ne/kViHLl8lrHsjW/i5ny/1ayxcTxiLJbkxsdtDD
<< zSgttxuC0lSFDyIITsH6xUzxH1/aacR9f2mvoGvf9tKUpSlKUr//2Q==
<< quit
```

Comment: You've got over a thousand rep, but didn't post any code...

Comment: My code was working more then 6months, I'm facing this problem since yesterday, I want to know when this error will come, I have checked with netstat the connection established and the debug file also updated

Comment: Did you set the `debug` and `debug_level` parameters? This should give you a lot more information on what went wrong. The _connection not established_ error comes when there is no socket established (i.e. `$obj->{socket}` has no value, and this is documented **in** the Perldoc!). Do you check the return code when you do a `Mail::Sender->new`?

Comment: yes, debug_level value is 4

Comment: @ungalnanban What's in the debug log file? And, did you check the return value of Mail::Sender->new? Note that `Mail::Sender->new` returns a negative value on failure and ***not*** undefined, null, or 0. Standard `if ( not $self ) {` will fail to detect an error.

Comment: In debug log file Its commming "This message is in MIME format. Since your mail reader does not understand this format, some or all of this message may not be legible."

Answer (score 0):

You say

> If I send 10 mails, only 2 mails successful send , remaining mails got this error.

and

> My code was working more then 6months, I'm facing this problem since yesterday

That suggests it's not your code, but something to do with the network or the mail server. You will need to capture part of the debug output where it stops working to see exactly what is happening.

It could well be a rate-limit setting on the mail-server, in which case a short pause between each message (or not sending lots of messages in parallel) should help. Also - some mail-servers can start rejecting/slowing connections when invalid messages/addresses get submitted.